# AWS - Cognito Federated identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, cloud, amazon-cognito

I have created a federated identities which contains:

1. **Identity pool ID** us-west-2:XXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
2. **User Pool ID** us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX
3. **App client ID** XXXXXX

When I try with **Identity pool ID** to connect to:
https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2:XXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/.well-known/jwks.json

I get:

```
{"message":"1 validation error detected: Value 'us-west-2:XXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX' at 'userPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\w-]+_[0-9a-zA-Z]+"}
```

If I try with **User Pool ID** us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX
https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json

```
{"message":"User pool us-west-2_ does not exist."}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to validate open id tokens issued from the identity pool? what do you mean by "connecting to" . Note: please hide the pool ID in your question.

Comment: @lgndrzzz, you seem to be adding the colon ':' into your URL for the first query and it's precisely telling you not do do that, and that it's expecting a userPoolId in that matches the regex '[\\w-]+_[0-9a-zA-Z]+'. maybe you're missing the \ at the start?

Comment: @OscarDeLeón I've tried, its not working.

Comment: @G.Bahaa Yes i do, i'm trying to validate the open id tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity pool id does not feature in the path, it is the user pool only `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`, as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/).

> https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX/.well-known/jwks.json

Comment: Is it exactly the thing i am doing but i receive the error that i descripted above. I don't understand your answer "the identity pool id does not feature in the path". As i said, https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX/.well-known/jwks.json is exactly what i'm using

Comment: No you had in your question the identity pool id instead of the user pool id (judging by the number of Xs)

Comment: app client id, identity pool id, are all irrelevant for your question, only user pool id is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to know the JWKs of the identity pool then you need to invoke this path
`/.well-known/jwks_uri`. the path `/.well-known/jwks.json` is only for the user pool.

Please note that this consumes time (my experience 0.9~1.0 sec). So I recommend saving these downloaded keys in the server/lambda in an object (kid: jwk) and verify if the key (corresponds to the token to be validated) exists before calling this URL (by checking the kid of the key for example).